# HTML in Yii2 GridView

Tags: html, gridview, yii2, formatting

I'm trying to display some HTML encoded strings as pure HTML in a column positioned in Yii2 GridView. The string that comes from the database looks like this:

```
Testing &lt;span class=&#039;test&#039;&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;
```

If I just display it using HTML decode `Html::decode($theStringAbove);` then I get this in the column:

```
Testing <span class='test'>HTML</span>
```

However, what I'm aiming at is simply getting `Testing HTML` and having the `span` tag around the HTML word in the code but not displayed as a string.

I've tried setting different values to the `format` attribute such as `raw`, `url` and `html` to no success. I also have no problem writing a custom function to return the correct output next to the `value` attribute, it's just that I can't figure out how to get to the output I need. Any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

EDIT: Here's a small code snippet if that's helpful:

```
[ 'format' => 'raw',
  'value' => function($model) { return Html::decode($model->text); },
  'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Some Label')]
```

Comment: Format `raw` should give you proper HTML output. Can you show the configuration for this problematic column of yours?

Comment: As noted above, I've already tried raw. I'll update the question with a small code snippet though.

Comment: Are you using a DetailView or a GridView? The code above looks to be for a DetailView.

Comment: I'm using GridView

Comment: @mmvsbg I've tested your snippet and I got `Testing HTML` visible with `Testing <span class="test">HTML</span>` in source. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. How did you achieve it?

Comment: @mmvsbg by using your exact snippet but replacing `$model->text` with `Testing &lt;span class=&#039;test&#039;&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;`. I think you have got this string encoded twice so it's actually something like `Testing &amp;lt;span class=&amp;#039;test&amp;#039;&amp;gt;HTML&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;` - try to decode it twice.

Comment: Nice catch, decoding twice works

Comment: ok, let me add proper answer for other with same problem.

Comment: Please do so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database output is probably encoded twice so instead of

```
Testing &lt;span class=&#039;test&#039;&gt;HTML&lt;/span&gt;
```

it's

```
Testing &amp;lt;span class=&amp;#039;test&amp;#039;&amp;gt;HTML&amp;lt;/span&amp;‌​gt;
```

Try to decode it twice like:

```
'value' => function ($model) {
    return Html::decode(Html::decode($model->replace));
}
```

Comment: @mmvsbg Proper solution added. Cheers

Comment: The `var_dump` of the output shows that it's encoded only once but I think what's going on is that the first decode just gets the encoded characters back to a string and the second one parses them as HTML. Two decodes one after another is indeed the solution. I'll just ask you to add this code snippet to your answer so that it's complete:
`'value' => function($model) { return Html::decode(Html::decode($model->replace)); }`

Comment: Nice catch. Decoding twice isn't the solution however. @mmvsbg you should fix your database data. The double encoding may be a symptom of a problem elsewhere.

Comment: It's true, this is only end-point solution, you should check database saving.

Comment: Yes, it's seems that there is an underlying problem here, I'll double check why the double encoding is happening. Nevertheless, thank you for your time and help.